# Automatically enable virtual and downloadable product settings

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

With WooCommerce, I'm using a vendor plugin which allows people to upload their own products.

However I would only like them to upload virtual and downloadable products.

Is there a way to remove (or even hide) these options on the normal woocommerce "add product page" and autocheck them?

Doesn't need to be impossible to circumvent as I moderate all submissions - just want to make the submission process as easy as possible.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to auto check `Virtual` and `Download` checkbox but you can hide the option, check [this link](http://cartible.com/tips/customizing-product-types-selectbox-in-woocommerce/).

Comment: Thanks, the main issue is to actually auto select though. Hiding would be great though if I could auto select

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For Virtual products only see the update at the end

This is possible but quiet long and complicated to test and explain... You will have to target this users in a condition by 2 ways, a specific user role or a specific capability of their user role.

Then is possible to hide some settings with injected CSS and the use of javascript/jQuery to set this hidden settings...

> In the working example below, I enable the **`'virtual'`** and **`'downloadable'`** settings cheeckboxes with jQuery and I hide them mostly totally with opacity CSS rule…

I use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`** action hook, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'hiding_and_set_product_settings' );
function hiding_and_set_product_settings(){

    ## ==> Set HERE your targeted user role:
    $targeted_user_role = 'administrator';

    // Getting the current user object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    // getting the roles of current user
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    if ( in_array($targeted_user_role, $user_roles) ){

        ## CSS RULES ## (change the opacity to 0 after testing)
        // HERE Goes OUR CSS To hide 'virtual' and 'downloadable' checkboxes
        ?>
        <style>
            label[for="_virtual"], label[for="_downloadable"]{ opacity: 0.2; /* opacity: 0; */ }
        </style>
        <?php

        ## JQUERY SCRIPT ##
        // Here we set as selected the 'virtual' and 'downloadable' checkboxes
        ?>

        <script>
            (function($){
                $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);
                $('input[name=_downloadable]').prop('checked', true);
            })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php
    }

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

> You will have to replace the 'administrator' user role by your specific targeted user role.
> You will have to set the opacity to 0, to completely hide that checkboxes.

Tested and works

---

**Addition For many user roles:**

1. Replace this line:

   $targeted_user_role = 'administrator';

… by this line:

```
$targeted_user_roles = array( 'administrator', 'shop_manager' );
```

2. And replace also this line:

   if ( in_array($targeted_user_role, $user_roles) ){

… by this line:

```
if ( array_intersect( $targeted_user_roles, $user_roles ) ){
```

> Now the code will work for many user defined user roles

---

**Set VIRTUAL option by default (and hide it):**

To hide and set by default virtual option you will use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'hide_and_enable_virtual_by_default' );
function hide_and_enable_virtual_by_default(){
    ?>
    ## HERE Goes OUR CSS To hide 'virtual & downloadable'
    <style>
        label[for="_virtual"], label[for="_downloadable"]{ opacity: 0; }
    </style>
    <?php
    ## JQUERY SCRIPT ##
    // Here we set as selected the 'virtual' checkboxes by default
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file. Tested and works.

Comment: Ah solved - stupid me forgot to close the PHP with ?>

Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: Above works for me but I try to get this working also for the Sold Individually checkbox on the inventory tab. IMHO it makes no sense to sell more then 1 copy of a downloadable file in one order. Adding the _sold_individually to the script part does not check it. Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

**Use this simple solution**:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', 'autocheck_vd');

function autocheck_vd( $arr ){
    $arr['virtual']     ['default'] = "yes"; 
    $arr['downloadable']['default'] = "yes"; 
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `wp-content\plugins\dokan-lite\templates\products\download-virtual.php` file to make virtual and downloadable products checkbox enabled.

It will look like this:

```
<div class="dokan-form-group dokan-product-type-container <?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">
<div class="content-half-part downloadable-checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked class="_is_downloadable" name="_downloadable" id="_downloadable"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Downloadable', 'dokan-lite' ); ?> <i class="fa fa-question-circle tips" aria-hidden="true" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Downloadable products give access to a file upon purchase.', 'dokan-lite' ); ?>"></i>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="content-half-part virtual-checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked class="_is_virtual" name="_virtual" id="_virtual"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Virtual', 'dokan-lite' ); ?> <i class="fa fa-question-circle tips" aria-hidden="true" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Virtual products are intangible and aren\'t shipped.', 'dokan-lite' ); ?>"></i>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="dokan-clearfix"></div>
```

To hide these options you can use css with "!important" to override the inline css of this element. Add this to any linked css file:

```
    .dokan-product-type-container{
        display:none !important;
    }
```