# Auto enable virtual option by default for a specific product type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have Woocommerce product type called "booking" and what I would like to do is to automatically mark it "virtual" upon creation.

Based on *"[Automatically enable virtual and downloadable product settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175983/automatically-enable-virtual-and-downloadable-product-settings/42177288#42177288)"* answer code, the code below sets all products to be virtual, while I want only "booking" product type to be by default virtual as opposed to simple or variable products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'enable_virtual_option' );
function enable_virtual_option(){

?>

        <script>
            (function($){
                $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);

            })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will auto enable virtual checkbox for a specific product type *(here "booking" type)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'hiding_and_set_product_settings' );
function hiding_and_set_product_settings(){
    global $post, $product_object;

    if ( $product_object->is_type('booking') ){
        ?>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);
            })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.