# How to auto check Downloadable and Virtual checkbox on Dokan frontend upload form?

Tags: dokan

I want to auto check on Downloadable and Virtual checkbox on Dokan plugin, this my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'hiding_and_set_product_settings' );
function hiding_and_set_product_settings(){

    ## ==> Set HERE your targeted user role:
    $targeted_user_roles = array( 'administrator', 'shop_manager', 'vendor', 'vendors' );

    // Getting the current user object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    // getting the roles of current user
    $user_roles = $user->roles;

    if ( array_intersect( $targeted_user_roles, $user_roles ) ){

        ## CSS RULES ## (change the opacity to 0 after testing)
        // HERE Goes OUR CSS To hide 'virtual' and 'downloadable' checkboxes
        ?>
        <style>
            label[for="_virtual"], label[for="_downloadable"]{ opacity: 0.2 !important; /* opacity: 0; */ }
        </style>
        <?php

        ## JQUERY SCRIPT ##
        // Here we set as selected the 'virtual' and 'downloadable' checkboxes
        ?>

        <script>
            (function($){
                $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);
                $('input[name=_downloadable]').prop('checked', true);
            })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php
    }

}
```

This in my function, child theme. I found this code from: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177288/6574214`. But this code only work for backend only, i want on dokan frontend upload form. Anyone know the code? I want comment on `https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177288/6574214` but i not have reputation for that... :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

Background : We are developing a website where vendors can sell digital products only. So we got this issue as we need to hide the options and keep downloadable and virtual enabled.

Here is the code you can use :

The above code you are using will work for woocommerce backend but to make it work in the frontend you need to use this hook : dokan_product_edit_after_options.

Ref : https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/developer-documentation/seller-dashboard-action-hooks/

Solution :

```
add_action( 'dokan_product_edit_after_options', 'pitby_dokan_preselect' );
function pitby_dokan_preselect(){
    ?>
    <style>
        label[for="_virtual"], label[for="_downloadable"]{ opacity: 0; }
    </style>
    <?php
    
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $('input[name=_virtual]').prop('checked', true);
            $('input[name=_downloadable]').prop('checked', true);
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks & Regards,
Vamsi.